# Rendering one collection using multiple templates

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, templating

I am building a news feed type feature which requires client-side rendering of feed items. There are different types of feed item which means each type requires a different template. I am currently using **UnderscoreJS** templating but am open to new ideas.

**I am using a method roughly like this:**

```
template : {
    f : "<li> <%= item.user.name %> uploaded a file </li>", // file upload
    m : "<li> <%= item.user.name %> just joined </li>", // just joined
    p : "<li> <%= item.user.name %> - <%= item.data.txt %> </li>" // comment
}

var html="";

for(i in feeditems){
    var item = feeditems[i];
    html+= _.template(template[item.type], { item: item });
}

$('#container').html(html);
```

**Is this the best way to address this problem?**

Comment: Depends... by "efficient" do you mean "fast" or do you mean "best for developer productivity"? I would suggest that anything that places HTML templates inside of JavaScript is going to be bad for the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From Underscore.js documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template)

**template**

> Compiles JavaScript templates into functions that can be evaluated for rendering. Useful for rendering complicated bits of HTML from JSON data sources.

From what I read it should be very efficient.

> Is it the most efficient?

Hard to say, the most efficient way would be to just hard code the string isn't? No lookups at all, however, sometimes it's better to sacrifice efficiency a bit to have more readable code.

Do you have any performance problem? If you don't, I wouldn't worry. If you do, instead of thinking if this is the most efficient template, I'd profile the application, because most probably the bottleneck is elsewhere.